# how to build kernel-tools-4.2.xx.rpm and kernel-ltools-libs-4.2.xx.rpm

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, centos

I am trying to upgrade Centos-7 kernel (kernel-3.10) to (Kernel-4.2.6) and for that I downloaded kernel from kernel.org and create rpm for the  custom configuration (arch x86_64)using "**make rpm**". 
Bellow packages were created:

- kernel-devel-4.2.6_xx.rpm
- kernel-4.2.6_xx.rpm
- kernel-headers-4.2.6_xx.rpm

but kernel-tools-xx.rpm and kernel-tools-libs-xx.rpm were not created.
Here is what I did:

1. Mounted centos-7-minimal.iso
2. replaced kernel-3.10.xx.rpm with kernel-4.2.6.xx.rpm from  /mnt/packages.
3. kept kernel-tools-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64.rpm and kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64.rpm as it is
4. updated Packages/TRANS.TBL with new kernel package.
5. created iso with xorriso as mkisofs command and installed Centos-7 while installing, faced error related to "**anaconda.py. /mnt/sysimg no file or directory**".

Do I need to update kernel-tools-xxx.rpm and kernel-tools-libs-xxx.rpm.
if yes how can I build these files after "***make rpm***". Because these files are not release on centos-7 rpm repo so that I can use theme directly.

Thanks